# Reading JSON data for a particular ID

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON data which is in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 145,
        "Name": "John",
        "company_name": "A",
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "country": "USA"
    },
    {
        "id": 500,
        "Name": "Mike",
        "company_name": "B",
        "email": "mike@gmail.com",
        "country": "London"
    },
    {
        "id": 100,
        "Name": "Sally",
        "company_name": "C",
        "email": "sally@gmail.com",
        "country": "USA"
    }
]
```

Now, suppose I ask the user to enter an id, say 100. Then I need to display all the details for this id.

I am supposed to do this as a part of a web application,where I have to invoke an display the fields of a particular id. This would have been easy if I had a hash like implementation and could display all parameters based on the key-id.

Can anybody tell me how this can be done using such kind of data?

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty elementary JavaScript. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:
(Assuming the you have a variable data with your Json Object).

```
function getid(id) {
 var nobj;     
data.forEach(function(obj) {
if(obj.id == id)
    nobj = obj;
});
return nobj    
}
var neededobj = getid(100);
    console.log(neededobj.Name + "\n" + neededobj.email + "\netc...");
```

But to get the Object you have to loop through your complete array,
until it finds the right Object

see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ4vK/6/)

Comment: Yes, it'll have to loop through all the objects in 'data'.

I just thought having a hash-like implementation will be much more effective.

Comment: What if I have nested JSON data, something like this:

    {
        "145": [
            {
                "name": "John",
                "email": "john@gmail.com",
                "country": "USA"
            }
        ],
        "500": [
            {
                "company_name": "Mike",
                "email": "mike@gmail.com",
                "country": "India"
            }
        ]
    }

Can I do something like data.145.name? Or some other way?

Comment: yes you could do `data[145][0].name`  ---
the [0] is required because the Object is stored in an Array of the propertie 145 in the data Object* ` `
and the [ ] have to be used instead of dot notation because u are accesing a propertie which is an number.
for strings there would be both possible e.g: either `data.prop1`or `data["prop1"]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Associative Array](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays),

the simplex one would be,

```
        var associativeArray = [];
        associativeArray["one"] = "First";
        associativeArray["two"] = "Second";
        associativeArray["three"] = "Third";

        alert(associativeArray.one);
```

And obviusly you can add json object in value place